# How to get the matplotlib inline output via jupyter_client

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, jupyter

I try to use jupyter_client to get the matplotlib output and display it in my web app. Here's what I did. But io.stdout is just a string. How can I get the actual image data of matplotlib. Thanks

```
In [6]: with capture_output() as io:
   ...:     reply = kc.execute_interactive("import matplotlib.pyplot as plt\n%matplotlib inline\ndata=[1,1,2,3,4]\nplt.figure()\nplt.plot(data)", timeout=TI
   ...: MEOUT)
   ...:
   ...:

In [8]: io.stdout
Out[8]: '[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1086a8d30>]<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x106f220f0>'
```

Comment: Maybe you spend some more words on what you are trying to achieve. "In my app" is a bit too unspecific to know where and how exactly you want to show the matplotlib output.

Comment: It's a web app, I suppose I should display image on this web app in the same approach of  jupyter notebook